# w_log.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c

okay?

I have a problem in C when I am using the log() and exp() math function.

The error is, using gdb to debug.

```
   (gdb) step
__log (x = -nan (0x8000000000000)) at w_log.c: 28
28 w_log.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
42 in w_log.c
(gdb) step
__ieee754_log_avx (x = -nan (0x8000000000000))
     at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c:78
78 ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c: No such file or directory.
```

The error happens in the line of code:

```
Z[t] = A[j] / ( X[t] * B[i] * pow( (2*PI) ,(1/2)) ) * exp( (-1) * ( pow( log(X[t]/C[k]), 2) / (pow( 2 * B[i] ,2)))) + 
( (1-A[j]) / ( X[t] * D[ii] * pow( (2*PI) ,(1/2)) ) * exp( (-1) * ( pow( log(X[t]/E[kk]), 2) / (pow( 2 * D[ii] ,2)))));
```

[The mathematical function is this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVBi6.gif)

> another error occurs for the "exp()" function, in the same way as the log

my make complie:

```
COMPILER = gcc
FLAGS = -lm -g

all: atd.exec
    @echo "Compiled!"

%.exec: %.o
    $(COMPILER) -o $@ $+ $(FLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILER) -o $@ -c $< $(FLAGS)

run: atd.exec
    ./atd.exec

test: atd.exec
    ./atd.exec > test.txt

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.exec
```

> Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: This is pretty common when you step into system libraries during your debugging.  Very often, the accompanying sources are not present on the system.  It is possible that they are available for installation, however; for instance, RedHat-family Linux distributions provide `-debuginfo` packages that you can install alongside the corresponding regular binary packages.

Comment: On the other hand, inasmuch as your problem is not at all likely to be in the system libraries, you also have the alternative of just stepping over calls to system library functions.

Comment: I was using the debug to find an error that was going on in the execution, but I ended up finding the error otherwise "manual brute force". The error occurs because the log () and exp () functions do not return the data when the input is zero. This is also a problem for me, since the first iteration of the function, all arrays have zero.

Comment: you need libraries compiled with debugging symbols, as you have and see where in the initial system were those located and install them in the same place in your system